# Unable to insert a List[Map[String, String]] to MongoDB via Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala

Having the following clause:

```
            collection.updateOne(
              Filters.and(myFilters: _*),
              Document(
                "$setOnInsert" -> Document(
                  "field" -> item.getAs[List[Map[String, String]]]("field")
                )
              ),
              UpdateOptions().upsert(true)
            )
```

On the `$setOnInsert` clause it will complain with `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'Document'`, and as far as I've been checking the method signature for a `Document` probably it isn't resolving it as a `CanBeBsonElements`.

Full trace of the error:

```
overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  (underlying: org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonDocument)org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document <and>
  (elems: org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonMagnets.CanBeBsonElements)org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document <and>
  (elems: org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonMagnets.CanBeBsonElement*)org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document <and>
  (json: String)org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document
 cannot be applied to ((String, List[Map[String,String]]))
                "$setOnInsert" -> Document(
```

I've already inserted `String` and `List[String]` elements without any issue, but can't really figure out how to insert a `List[Map[String, String]]`.

Comment: The problem is that the magnets do not support `Maps`, you may either see if you can read the data as a `List[Document]` or just do `item.getAs[List[Map[String, String]]]("field").map(_.toList)`